# The regex for a simple case

Tags: regex

Can someone give me the regular expression to validate that the string is `_ _._ _ _` only numbers, with a point at the 3rd position.

Comment: **Show us what you have tried**.  We don't just spew the answers for you on command.

Comment: This is very basic regex. Which part is it that you're stuck with?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that would be something like `^\d\d\.\d\d\d$` (or `^\d{2}\.\d{3}$`), depending on which regex engine you're using.

Depending on what sort of matching function you're using, you may not need the `^` and `$` (start and end) markers either.

If your engine is an older one that doesn't recognise `\d`, you can use `[0-9]` instead.